# Core Data Lock Options when an object is fetched

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

Are there possibilities to fetch an object in Core Data at different layer or with different lock options?

I notice that if I fetch an object from Core Data and i modify some of its properties, i can't re-fetch the same object until i save the context. I would be able to fetch multiple times the same object and modify each time some properties and save only at the end (all modification are made by the same thread so there are not problem of incoherency).
Core data supports this lock strategy?

I need it because i have hundreds of objects and if i save each time, the system become slow, but also i can't keep in memory all the object fetched.

**EDIT:**

I found this on the Apple Documentation, but it works only for properties and not for relationship in my project. The only difference I think that I'm using a private context because the fetch is on a background thread.

[image]

Comment: *"... i can't re-fetch the same object until i save the context."* What? Why not?

Comment: I can only if I didn't change any of its properties or relationship.

Comment: Sorry, only if I change a relationship I have this problem

Comment: You should be able to fetch it at any time. What happens when you try to fetch it?

Comment: no object is returned. I try to : fetch the object, modify a relationship, refetch the object. The second time the object is not funded